# Julia IntervalRootFinding doesn't allow function variables to be vector or matrix?

Tags: matlab, types, package, julia, roots-toolkit

I'm new to Julia and just trying to move my MATLAB code to `IntervalRootFinding` package to find all potential roots. Apologies if I'm using my habits of writing matrix operations in MATLAB and didn't understand the way Julia treats variable types.

I'm trying to find all roots of a function of 6 variables (one vector and one 2x2 matrix.) My first version of codes looked like this

```
function EXAMPLE1((a, b); param=param_default)
    (Some operations taking a as a 2x1 vector and b as a 2x2 matrix.)
    return SVector{6}(condition1, condition2,...,condition6)
end
```

I then realized it's not possible to tell the `roots` function the interval of the elements in the matrix, so I rewrote my function so that it took scalar variables as input. But since all my calculations are way more efficient doing in matrix so I constructed the vector and matrix in the first line of the function, which made my codes to

```
function EXAMPLE2((a1, a2, b11, b12, b21, b22); param=param_default)
    a = [a1 a2]';
    b = [b11 b12; b21 b22];
    (Same operations taking a as a 2x1 vector and b as a 2x2 matrix.)
    return SVector{6}(condition1, condition2,...,condition6)
end

# Define intervals and finding roots
A = 0..10
B = 0..1
rts = roots(EXAMPLE2, A × A × B × B × B × B )
```

When I tested the function using random inputs like

```
    EXAMPLE2(1.0,1.0,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3)
```

it went through and gave me `6-element SVector{6, Float64} with indices SOneTo(6):`. But when I run `roots` on my function, I got the following error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Interval{Float64})
```

and the line `a = [a1 a2]';` was marked red.

It looks like a data type mismatch issue - it can't assign a `Float64 Interval` as an element of the array `a`? Is it because `IntervalRootFinding` or `roots` only works with functions that operate on scalars, and not support functions of multi-dimensional arrays?

Another way of asking is, since I'm just trying to find all roots of a function of matrix, are there better packages in Julia for this purpose? More flexible for matrices, like `fsolve` in MATLAB but gives all roots?

Rewriting my functions into scalar operation is almost impossible, I won't bother to try. Thanks very much for anyone discussing this.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I don't understand correctly is your problem i R6 -> R6, so It seems like it's a (non-linear) system of equations. Root finding procedures (Roots.jl or IntervalRootFinding.jl) works from R ->R, so I don't think it's the correct package for that.

With that said, the error seems weird. Can you post a minimal running example and expected result? With that, I could try to actually solve the system in my computer.

Comment: An alternative for fsolve is NonlinearSolve.jl and NLSolve.jl.  If you are also looking for all results, maybe changing your problem from a nonlinear system of equations to an optimization problem and using https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalOptimisation.jl could help